# How to hide some columns with EF + lambda expression (for WCF QueryInterceptor)

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, wcf-data-services, interceptor

I have a Web App with a WCF OData Service. I have a model called Guest with some properties: Id, FullName, Username, Email...

The WCF data service works like a feed, so I want to hide the Email columns, but I do not know how.

```cs
public Expression<Func<Guest, bool>> OnQueryGuests()
{
    if (!IsAuthenticated())
        return c => c________;//what should return here???
}
```

My temporary solution is to disable the service for all users not logged on.

Comment: Same question duplicate at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23163035/637142

Comment: I added a possible solution at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23163035/637142  look at the edit part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With entity framework you will need to project the results into a subclass then tell WCF Data Services that the subclass is the entity.  By intercepting the IQueryable this is all possible. It's a little bit of work but with the help of Derrick VanArnam MS [Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Entity-Framework-a958cffb/sourcecode?fileId=95130&pathId=263687793) I was able to create an expression interceptor that would modify the expression tree to remove the bindings of properties that aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

return c => c.ToList().Select(item => new { Value1 = item.Value1, Value2 = item.Value2 });

Select all your columns except the ones you want to hide in your anonymous object..

Answer (score 1):

What about building your own class and use this as a viewmodel?

like

```
public class publicUser{
  public int id{get;set;}
  public string name{get;set;}
  //and so on...
}
```

and your select should be:

```
List<publicUser> data = (from c in datasource..
                                                select new publicUser(){
                                                    name= c.name,
                                                    id= c.id
                                                }).ToList();
```