# WCF data service permission on individual table columns instead of on whole entities

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services, queryinterceptor

**Note the bounty is asking about the edited portion of this question. First part is describing the problem**

I have a table

```
Customer 
-----
Name
Address
SocialSecurity
Phone
Etc....
```

I have another table called

```
Permissions     
-----
IdOfUser

Can_C_Address
Can_R_Address
Can_U_Address
Can_D_Address

Can_C_Phone
Can_R_Phone
Can_U_Phone
Can_D_Phone

Etc...
```

*note CRUD stands for create, read, update and delete*

How can I make sure **at the server side** that a user query the database as:

```
contex.Customers.ToList();
```

pretend the user that made that request to the wcf data service had no permission to see the social security. **I will like that list to return with `null` social security numbers. How can I do that?**

*It is a lot of work to separate each property/tableColumn into a different entity. For example having CustomerPhone, CustomerSocial, etc all as different entities.*

---

### ---------------------------------------- Edit --------------------------------------

I found a weird solution! I do not know if it is safe though. Here it is:

Lets say I have an entity called Users. Users have a phone number, social security, address etc. My problem was that I wanted to hide the social security when someone queried the database for example. **To solve that problem what I did was I CREATED AN OPERATION/METHOD WITH THE SAME NAME AS THE ENTITY** In other words I added the method:

```
[WebGet]
public IEnumerable<Data.Sub.User> Users()
{
    return this.CurrentDataSource.Users.ToList().Select(x => { x.SocialSecurity = ""; return x; });
}
```

Then on my client side when I did:

```
var context = new Data.DatabaseReference.MyEntity(); 
context.Users.ToList();  // WHEN I INVOKE THAT METHOD I SEE THAT I NEVER GET SOCIAL SECURITY!
```

**Is it safe to take this approach?**

Comment: I bet you could make a somewhat messy solution that uses reflection, but it would be a little long to post as an answer here.

Comment: I've posted on your other stackoverflow question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203482/operation-instead-of-query-interceptor-wcf-data-services/23253919#23253919 that works for root entities but not for navigation properties.

Comment: What provider are you using?  EF or reflection provider?

Comment: I have the solution up and running but it's a bit big to post all the code on stack overflow,  I'll probably just post the general idea and post the code more on my blog.  Plus I need to clean it up.  I went with #3.  Since your not the only one that wanted it and I even wanted it before WCF Data Service went into maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four options and none of them is going to be fun.

1) If you are using the reflection provider handle the security at the root query.  If it needs to be dynamic you will probably end up using ExpressionTrees to do the projection.

2) Create a custom data service provider - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx  If you are using Entity Framework you will need to also modify the expression tree and remove all their null projections they add when using a custom provider.  This isn't for the faint of heart.

3) Intercept the IQueryable and using an ExpressionVisitor remove or replace any properties that shouldn't be projected.  For example of how to intercept the query you can see what you need to do wrap IQueryable here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitek/archive/2012/01/07/projections-in-custom-providers-simple-solution.aspx.  There was a Microsoft blog on how to intercept IQueryable and replace all the constants with properties so EF would send parameters that was good but I can't find it right now.

4) Switch from WCF Data Services over to Web API where you have more control.  From this blog is what they are recommending anyways http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/27/future-direction-of-wcf-data-services.aspx

That's if you just want to do it for the read in crud. Besides #2 that doesn't really touch the create, update and delete part of CRUD.

- Update
  For option #3 you can read how to do it on my blog http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Entity-Framework-a958cffb/sourcecode?fileId=95130&pathId=263687793

Comment: +1 thanks for the help! Prob going to accept your answer if I dont find anything better now.

Comment: How do I handle security at the root query?

Comment: If you are using the reflection provider that means you are exposing a public property that returns type of IQueryable.  In the getter you would need to add your logic to project out what property's should be null and return that as the IQueryable.  Most likely you will get into expressiontree's if you want it to be dynamic.  ExpresionTree's seem hard at first but once you get using them they aren't so bad.